# X-SES-RECEIPT header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When receiving an email on SES I see that there is X-SES-RECEIPT header, however on amazon docs I can't find anything according to what is it.

Do You know what is the value of that header and how to decrypt it?

Comment: I wonder if it is simply a Unique ID that can be used to match the message with the log files?

Comment: I thought that maybe that was some kind of encoded base64 data and then jwt, however was unable to do it ;/